# How to convert EXT3 to EXT4 root (/) partition without access to the system or media drives?

Tags: linux, filesystems

We have a 'baremetal' VPS hosted server with our provider.
Everything on this 'instance' is in one main root / parition.

If I don't have access to this system, how can I convert this to an ext4 file system?

is this even possible?

This is running Ubuntu 10.04 kernel version  2.6.36 .

thanks.

Comment: Which VPS technology? What is the filesystem now?

Comment: Xen 3.4 - running EXT3

Comment: It would be best if your provider gave you remote console access; Xen is perfectly capable of this. Anyway, @JeffFerland's instructions below are probably best for you. Take a backup before starting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bring the system down to single user mode. This works best if you have a remote console connection available (VNC or ssh wired to a virtual serial console). If you don't, you'll need to fiddle a bit taking all the services offline except SSH.
2. Edit your /etc/fstab to show your root partition as type ext4.
3. Remount your root partition as read only.
4. Follow [these conversion instructions](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Ext4#Converting_an_ext3_filesystem_to_ext4).
5. Reboot.

I'd try it on a VM first beforehand... and before that I'd take a deep look at **why** you're making that conversion and whether it's really worthwhile.

Comment: no console access - But apparently the host can do it themselves if I give them the instructions.  The reason for upgrading is we have some very large InnoDB tables 30+gb) with lots of read/writes - we are noticing fairly large IO - there is no swapping happening. EXT4 has some performance increases.

Comment: First I will check mysql config to search some performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

while it is possible, it is quite risky. you should back up the data before rebooting. it is easy to forget something and the system might drop to a maintenance mode. so i would not recommend it unless you have have out of band access to your server. take a look at this:

https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto#Converting_an_ext3_filesystem_to_ext4